# Golang: update slice in loop for empty interface

Tags: go, interface, range, reflect

For example, we have 3 CSV files and common for all is Email column. In first file are Name and Email, in another are Email (plus different info) and no Name field. So, if I need to fill in 2 and 3 files field Name based on the correspondence of the Name and Еmail from the first file than... I wrote code like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"

    "github.com/jszwec/csvutil"
)

type User struct {
    Name  string `csv:"name"`
    Email string `csv:"email"`
}

type Good struct {
    User
    Dt string `csv:"details"`
}

type Strange struct {
    User
    St string `csv:"status"`
    Dt string `csv:"details"`
}

var lst map[string]string

func readCSV(fn string, dat interface{}) error {
    raw, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fn)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Cannot read CSV: %w", err)
    }

    if err := csvutil.Unmarshal(raw, dat); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Cannot unmarshal CSV: %w", err)
    }
    return nil
}

func fixNames(fl string, in interface{}) error {
    if err := readCSV(fl, in); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("CSV: %w", err)
    }
    switch in.(type) {
    case *[]Good:
        var vals []Good
        for _, v := range *in.(*[]Good) {
            v.Name = lst[strings.TrimSpace(strings.ToLower(v.Email))]
            vals = append(vals, v)
        }
        in = vals
    case *[]Strange:
        var vals []Strange
        for _, v := range *in.(*[]Strange) {
            v.Name = lst[strings.TrimSpace(strings.ToLower(v.Email))]
            vals = append(vals, v)
        }
        in = vals
    }

    b, err := csvutil.Marshal(in)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Cannot marshal CSV: %w", err)
    }
    ext := filepath.Ext(fl)
    bas := filepath.Base(fl)
    err = ioutil.WriteFile(bas[:len(bas)-len(ext)]+"-XIAOSE"+ext, b, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Cannot save CSV: %w", err)
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var users []User
    if err := readCSV("./Guitar_Contacts.csv", &users); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("CSV: %s", err)
    }
    lst = make(map[string]string)
    for _, v := range users {
        lst[strings.TrimSpace(strings.ToLower(v.Email))] = v.Name
    }

    var usersGood []Good
    if err := fixNames("./Guitar-Good.csv", &usersGood); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("fix: %s", err)
    }

    var usersStrange []Strange
    if err := fixNames("./Guitar-Uknown.csv", &usersStrange); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("fix: %s", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("OK")
}
```

in this code I don't like part in func fixNames where is switch:

```
switch in.(type) {
    case *[]Good:
        var vals []Good
        for _, v := range *in.(*[]Good) {
            v.Name = lst[strings.TrimSpace(strings.ToLower(v.Email))]
            vals = append(vals, v)
        }
        in = vals
    case *[]Strange:
        var vals []Strange
        for _, v := range *in.(*[]Strange) {
            v.Name = lst[strings.TrimSpace(strings.ToLower(v.Email))]
            vals = append(vals, v)
        }
        in = vals
    }
```

because I just repeat code in part where *in.(**SOME_TYPE**). I want one loop and one action for different types, structs where are Name and Email fields...

Also was idea to do it with reflection smth. like this:

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(in)
v = v.Elem()
for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
    fmt.Println(v.Index(i))
}
```

but I do not know what to do next, how to add in that **v** value for Name

Answer (score 1):

You don't need reflection for this particular case. You can clean the code up by realizing that you are only working on the `User` part of the structs, and that you can simplify the type switch:

```
fix:=func(in *User) {
  in.Name = lst[strings.TrimSpace(strings.ToLower(in.Email))]
}
switch k:=in.(type) {
  case *[]Good:
     for i := range *k {
         fix( &(*k)[i].User )
     }
  case *[]Strange:
     for i := range *k {
         fix( &(*k)[i].User )
     }
}
```

You have to repeat the for loop, but above code does the correction in place.

You can clean up a bit more by not passing a reference to the slice.

Comment: There are still: 
for i := range *t {
    fix(&(*t)[i].User)
}
in 2 places, totally the same. And what if I add a new structs? Like []Good2, []Strange666, etc.? Again, new case, new copy-paste. Your proposed solution quite niceing code but not too much, sorry

Comment: Those are different types and without generics support this is a performant way of doing what you need. You can probably do better by changing your design. Reflection will not be as clean or performant.

Comment: Ок, and what do you think, how design must be changed?

Comment: Remove type switch, write two loops for two different structs, do not use interface{}. You have to write two almost-identical for loops without reflection, It is type safe and performs well. Reflection is slower, and code involving reflection for these type of scenarios doesn't age well.

Answer (score 1):

With reflect package, you can do that like this.

```golang
func fixNames(fl string, in interface{}) error {
    //other code

    v := reflect.ValueOf(in)
    if v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        arr := v.Elem()
        fmt.Println(arr.Len())
        if arr.Kind() == reflect.Slice || arr.Kind() == reflect.Array {
            for i := 0; i < arr.Len(); i++ {
                elem := arr.Index(i)
                f := elem.FieldByName("Name")
                f.SetString("NameOfUser")
            }
        }
    }

    // other code
}
```

Also playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/KrGvLVprslH